# Есть ли видеоплееры с отображением миллисекунд на Mac?

Tags: видео, mac, mediaplayer, поиск-программ

Нужно просмотреть видео формата "mp4" с точностью до минут, секунд и миллисекунд для определенной задачи - анализа.

Операционная система: macOS Catalina, версия: 10.15.7

Как я поняла есть видеоплееры с отображением миллисекунд только на windows, на Mac альтернатив и решений найти не удалось. Может быть кто-то сталкивался с подобным вопросом и смог его решить.
Уже пробовала устанавливать VLC плеер, но там нужен определенный плагин, чтобы открыть возможность просмотра по миллисекундам, такой плагин установить на мак, к сожалению, мне не удалось.

Comment: vlc смотрели https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-macosx.uk.html ?

Comment: Да, смотрела, не получилось установить плагин с миллисекундами на Mac, он не работает :(

Comment: может ffmpeg нарисовать поверх видео? -vf drawtext="fontsize=72:x=12:y=12:`
timecode='00\:00\:00\:00':rate=25:fontcolor='white':`
boxcolor=0x000000AA:box=1" `

Comment: mplayer с -osd-fractions 1 делает почти то, что нужно — показывает сотые. Существует везде, насколько я знаю. И посмотрите на SMPlayer.